# Poloniex C# API - error when trying to withdraw ETH

Tags: c#, ethereum, poloniex

I am using the Poloniex C# API available here: [Poloniex C#](https://github.com/Jojatekok/PoloniexApi.Net).

I am trying to withdraw ETH from my account like this:

```
private string ETHWithdrawalAddress;

public async void WithdrawETH(double amount)
{
 var addresses = await client.Wallet.GetDepositAddressesAsync();
 ETHWithdrawalAddress = addresses["ETH"];
 await client.Wallet.PostWithdrawalAsync("ETH", amount,   ETHWithdrawalAddress);
}
```

but I'm receiving this error

> Could not create an instance of type
> Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.WalletTools.IGeneratedDepositAddress.
>
> Type is an
> interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

Any help with solving this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the last line of the `PostWithdraw()` method in the API

```
PostData<IGeneratedDepositAddress>("withdraw", postData);
```

to

```
PostData<GeneratedDepositAddress>("withdraw", postData);
```